# Create multiple arrays from multiple dataframes in pandas

Tags: arrays, pandas, dataframe

I want to create multiple arrays based on multiple dataframes.
I have 4 different dataframes (df, df1, df2, df3) and want to create all_points (all_points, all_points1, all_points2, all_points3) and dm for each dataframe (dm, dm1, dm2, dm3, dm4)
Is it possible to do this within a funtion?

```
all_points = df[['lat', 'lng']].values

dm = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(all_points,
                                  all_points,
                                  get_distance)

all_points1 = df1[['lat', 'lng']].values

dm1 = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(all_points1,
                                  all_points1,
                                  get_distance)
```

I tried something like this but it is not working:

```
def b(all_points):
    all_points = df[['lat', 'lng']].values


    return all_points

all_points = b(df)
all_points1 = b(df1)
...
```

I am happy to receive an answer!

Comment: Are you just wanting to combine them in the one table?  Stacking them vertically perhaps?

Comment: I do not want to stack them in general, I want to create thesee variables for every dataframe within a funtction or something

Comment: What error did you get when you run the `b` function you created?

Comment: There is no error but the all_point, all_point1... contains the same values and not dataframe specific

Comment: Ah I see where your mistake is, replace `allpoints` parameter in your function with `df`